# Guardar el valor del select cada vez que le doy al boton "volver"

Tags: php

Hola mi intención es que cada vez que pulse el botón volver la opción elegida en el select continue, pero al pulsarl el boton de volver se pone vacio.

```
 if ($bd->consulta_vacia($rel)){
            echo "<p><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> Sin ra para selección de categorias, contacte con administración.</p>";
        }else{
            echo "<label>Ra:</label>";
            echo "<select name='obs_ra' id='obs_ra' data-placeholder='&nbsp;' class='chosen-select'>";
                echo "<option value=''></option>";
                while ($y=$bd->obtener_fila($rel,0)){
                    $idx=$y['id'];
                    $pob=trim($y['poblacio']);
                    $nom=mb_strtoupper(trim($y['nom'])); if (!empty($pob)) $nom="$nom ($pob)";
                    echo "<option value='$idx'>$nom</option>";
                }
            echo "</select>";
        }

echo "<a href='her_coger.php?id=$id&material=$material' class='btn_enviar'>Volver</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes manejarlo con cookies o sesiones. esto es un metodo que se usa para guardar informacion que despues puede ser recuperada por la aplicacion.
tambuen puedes usar javascript para agregar la selecion al ref, pues veo que no estas usando formularios.

si no saves mucho usa jquery que como sugerencia es asi:

```
$("#obs_ra").val();//obtiene el valor del select
```

aqui una referencia: https://jsfiddle.net/enlinea777/zrn3tLbs/15/

asi puedes recuperar el valor del select en el volver para enviarlo cuando vuelvas.